# How to show alert with condition and setTimeout

Tags: reactjs

Main problem: I have page which change view onClick tab; on second tab I want to start displaying alert with information.

My trial: My code works partially, I can setTimeout, but i have problem with conditional render. The component display with first render on first tab, but not interact with click Tab.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let timer1;
        if (tabs === second_component) {
            let timer1 = setTimeout(() => setAlertClose(false), 9000);
        }

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer1);
        };
    }, [mode]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to recheck this condition when the tab is changed, you will need to add tabs in the dependancy array for the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timer1;
    if (tabs === second_component) {
        let timer1 = setTimeout(() => setAlertClose(false), 9000);
    }

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer1);
    };
}, [mode, tabs]);
```